# How to properly scrape python website table?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to scrape some data using python but it gets me the following error:

```
rows = table.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I tried some other sites with tables and its working perfectly..can someone please help me out?

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cointobuy.io'

r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', {"class": "t-chart"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
cols = row.find_all('td')
cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['#', 'Name', 'Current Price', 'Safety Rank', 'Potential Profit', 'Potential Price'])

print(result)
```

i also wanted to send myself (mail) any update when something has changed in the table. any idea's for that?

Comment: If the page does not contain a table with class equal to t-chart, your variable `table` will be None.

Comment: This page does have a tbody table with tr classes inside.

Comment: You can't assume that every website will populate the DOM in the same way. This page, for example, has all the table information baked into a JavaScript string-literal, and then it uses JavaScript to asynchronously populate the DOM. At least, that's what it does when you view the page in a browser. BeautifulSoup doesn't do all the fancy JavaScript stuff a browser does. It just parses HTML. In this case you could write a regular expression to extract and parse the string-literal that's baked in, but I just tried it, and it looks like some of the data is ill-formulated, and can't be parsed.

Comment: You're probably better off ditching this website, and getting your cryptocurrency price data elsewhere. There are some websocket- and REST APIs out there, but they're not free, and you need to purchase an API key. A websocket API would be ideal in your case, since you want certain events to trigger when an asset's price changes (sending emails, for example), and websockets will stream things like price changes to you.